# How to handle a question where the problem turns out to be unreproducible?

Tags: discussion

(Trying to learn to be a responsible member...) I've been monitoring a question where the problem turns out to be non-reproducible - the dev machine was "hiccuping" and the problem went away:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33936359/custom-document-properties-retrieving-stored-properties-word-c-sharp

The OP states this in a Comment. There is no Answer and there will never be an Answer. As far as I can see, the thread has no intrinsic value.

I'd like to flag it, but don't know what the appropriate way to do so would be. Or should it be left as is?

Comment: How about: Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic > "This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced**..."?

Comment: This seems like it could be a [tag:faq] post.

Comment: @zzzzBov Yes. For "newbies" it's difficult to keep straight what flag options are where, especially when you add the various Review categories to the Q & A. Not sure what the optimal format would be for looking things up, though...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

> I'd like to flag it, but don't know what the appropriate way to do so would be.

A close reason for exactly this situation exists under the "Off-Topic" sub-menu:

[image]

Comment: yes, thank you. I was looking for that, but wasn't finding it... <sigh>

Comment: I hate fun but these are not freehand circles...

Comment: @idmean <shrug> my snapshot tool doesn't do freehand circles without a lot of mess (I use a tracker ball). Basically I don't care about some strange meme. I'm here to write quality answers not cater to all of the "in" jokes ;)

Comment: Yeah... but [freehand is better](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AuMAQ.jpg)

Comment: @TinyGiant Give me one **good** reason why it is better? It looks a mess ;) And don't point me to [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775) because I don't agree with it.

Comment: "Because I said so" is a good reason right? :)

Comment: @TinyGiant Well I say it isn't ;) Scrappy freehand circle are unprofessional - it looks like they are drawn by a drunk 2 year old ;) and no clearer than a red rectangle with a yellow background to draw the eyes to the appropriate places.

Comment: Well, you are allowed to have your own opinion, even if it is wrong. :)

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery and freehand circles :p

Comment: @DavidPostill I suggest a compromise. Please redraw this with free-hand rectangles. You may color them in yellow by hand if desired. If you do so, please do not stay inside the lines.

Comment: +1 for succinct answer with concise, high quality visual aid

Comment: The thing about freehand circles is it is obviously done afterwards and not part of the original thing. I spent ages trying to find the flag reason which had a red rectangle and yellow background as this looks like it is done through HTML/CSS on the site itself